# Google App Engine Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am working on android google app engine and while creating a backend lib i am getting an error:

```
    {

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: java.net.UnknownHostException: webapis-discovery.appspot.com
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.generateAndWriteDiscovery(SwarmApiCreator.java:313)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: webapis-discovery.appspot.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.postRequest(CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.java:75)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.generateDiscoveryDoc(CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.generateAndWriteDiscovery(SwarmApiCreator.java:310)
    ... 5 more
}
```

I don't know what went wrong. I unable to find any solution